# Reset activity and reputation

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

Today, I logged in to SO on a new PC, and found my rep back at 101 with all activity erased. Any idea how to recover it?

Comment: Merged.  Try logging in again.

Answer (score 3):

That means you accidentally created new account at https://stackoverflow.com/users/740957/ray

here is your original account:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/581528/ray

See how to request an account merge on [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Comment: Whoops. Can I get back on the right one? Not sure about the OpenID

Comment: @Ray, take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste